# SharedPreferences, doubles and arrays in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I have a user to insert 10 numbers that will be stored in an array. From this number the average is calculated and stored in a double.
Now I want send the array and the double to another activity but I don't see any option when I type editor.put.
How can I do that?

```
public int[] number = new int[10];
public double avg;

...

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.put... 
editor.put... 
editor.commit();
```

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: Why not pass via `Intent` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to pass these values to another `Activity` and not hold on to them for longer term use, just embed them as an extra in the `Intent` used to start the other `Activity`.

Just use your own `String` keys which are known to both `Activity` classes and call:

[`putExtra(YOUR_INT_ARRAY_KEY, yourIntArray)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int[]))

[`putExtra(YOUR_DOUBLE_KEY, yourDoubleVal)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20double))

Comment: I assume he needs an example.

Comment: just added a couple of minor lines of clarification with links to the Android docs.

Comment: I do need to save them in the next activity.

Comment: It's not very efficient, but for a relatively small number of values (such as the 10 you are using) you could always create a `String` representation of each int, then create a `Set<String>` containing all of the values you wish to save.  From there you can use `putStringSet()` to save it off and `getStringSet()` to retrieve it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just use JSON if that isn't too much overhead for you.

See this example:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    jsonArray.put(i, number[i]);
}
...
editor.put("YOUR_KEY", jsonArray.toString());
...
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(myPrefs.getString("YOUR_KEY", ""));
array.get(i);
...
```

Here the Link to the API. JSONObject may also be worth a look at:

[JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

[JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way. It works well.

```
public int[] number = new int[10];
public double avg;

...

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();

editor.putFloat(AVERAGE, avg);


StringBuilder intArrayToString = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++)
{
    intArrayToString.append(number[i]).append(",");
}

editor.putString(INT_TO_STRING, intArrayToString.toString());

editor.commit();
```